# How to handle relative imports in Jest with ESM modules written in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest

I am using Jest for my unit tests. My source code is written in TypeScript and compile to ESM output by setting `tsconfig.json` property `module` to `ES2020`. Additionally, I am using [`ts-jest`](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support) as a `transformer` to convert the code on the fly.

The setup is working fine as long as I don't import relative files in ESM modules. As per [node.js ESM documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions), the extension is mandatory when specifying `import` source.

Since it is clear from [various](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577#issuecomment-309169829) [threads](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13422#issuecomment-275458975) that typescript doesn't rewrite import paths or add any extension to the compiled JS code, I manually add extension to the import statements like like this:

```
// TS CODE
import { catalog } from './catalog.js';

// Compiled ESM2020 target and module
import { catalog } from './catalog.js';
```

The the **main problem** is that when ts-jest is transpiling the code on the fly, this file `catalog.js` simply doesn't exist in `src` folder. Instead original file with `.ts` extension as `catalog.ts` exists! And, jest complains that this file doesn't exist which is right:

```
Cannot find module './catalog.js' from 'src/index.ts'
```

So, how do I get around this problem?

> On a side note, I need to stick to ESM output since I am using many ESM only packages and TypeScript compile doesn't retain dynamic `import` statements. It converts those to `require` statements. This is already [controversial discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43329) as CommonJS supports dynamic imports.

For reference, this is my `jest.config.js` file:

```js
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
  collectCoverage: true,

  // A preset that is used as a base for Jest's configuration
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm-legacy',

  // The paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment before each test
  setupFiles: ['./src/jest-setup.ts'],

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: 'node',

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.[t]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[t]s?(x)'],

  // A map from regular expressions to paths to transformers
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  }
};

export default config;
```

Comment: What does your jest config look like?

Comment: @morganney Added the Jest configuration.

Comment: The ts-jest docs you linked to mentioned `extensionsToTreatAsEsm` needs to be set to `.ts`. Have you tried that? https://jestjs.io/docs/next/configuration#extensionstotreatasesm-arraystring

Comment: The preset `ts-jest/presets/default-esm-legacy` should take care of it.

Comment: Should or does? Why not add it and be explicit, at least to troubleshoot?

Comment: Already did. Verified with debug output.

Comment: @HarshalPatil did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: Nope. No solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the section ["Use ESM presets"](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/#use-esm-presets) of the ESM support part of the ts-jest documentation, the example configuration contains the following part, which is missing in your configuration:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
```